# subtype in Geospatial Sparql error

Tags: geospatial, sparql, allegrograph

I use SPARQL to request:

```
select distinct ?place ?label ?lat ?lng where {
                    GEO OBJECT 
                    SUBTYPE "http://franz.com/ns/allegrograph/3.0/geospatial/spherical/km/-180.0/180.0/-90.0/90.0/50.0"
                    HAVERSINE (POINT(105.8522, 21.0287), 1.0 KM) {
                                            ?place vtio:hasGeoPoint ?loc. 
                                            ?place rdf:type vtio:FastFood.
                                            ?place rdfs:label ?label. 
                    ?place vtio:hasLatitude ?lat.
                                            ?place vtio:hasLongtitude ?lng.
                    } where {
                    } FILTER(lang(?label)='vn')
                                          } LIMIT  5
```

But when i execute it, There is an error:

```
Executing query failed:
QUERY FAILED: Geospatial subtype
"http://franz.com/ns/allegrograph/3.0/geospatial/spherical/km/-180.0/180.0/-90.0/90.0/50.0"
not found.
```

I use allegrograph 4.12.1 . So, What `SUBTYPE` I should use, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have to register spherial type first. I did it through JENA API:

```
URI sphericalTypeURI=conn.registerSphericalType(50,"km");
```

where `conn` is current connection (instance of `AGRepositoryConnection`)